# Docker refused to connect

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

After I `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`, if I go to `localhost:5000` in my browser (Which is the port I exposed in the yml file), I get:

This site can’t be reached. 
localhost refused to connect.

However, if I go to `192.168.99.100:5000`, the container loads. Is there a way I can fix this issue?

Comment: Post your Docker Compose YAML file.

Comment: Please post your Docker Compose file as well as the output of: `docker version`.

Comment: `fin system start`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind your container port to 127.0.0.1:5000.

By default, if you don't specify an interface on port mapping, Docker bind that port to all available interfaces (0.0.0.0). If you want to bind a port only for localhost interface (127.0.0.1), you have to specify this interface on port binding.

**Docker**

```
docker run ... -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 ...
```

**Docker Compose**

```
ports:
 - "127.0.0.1:5000:5000"
```

For further information, check Docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: I am a bit new in docker. Can you refer me to the doc part that mentions this?