# Docker R Shiny app 0.0.0.0 refused to connect when trying to view in local browser

Tags: r, docker, shiny, docker-compose

Read:

- [Docker refused to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507979/docker-refused-to-connect)

I have created a simple shiny app using the rstudio template app.r when creating a new shiny web app.

My directory:

```
doug:~/Projects/test$ pwd
/home/work/Projects/test
doug:~/Projects/test$ ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 work work  178 Sep 24 18:27 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 work work  240 Sep 24 18:16 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x 2 work work 4096 Sep 24 13:55 test_app
-rw-r--r-- 1 work work  205 Sep 24 13:45 test.Rproj
```

My Docker file:

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse

COPY test_app mountpoints/apps/test_app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y
    
WORKDIR mountpoints/apps/test_app

EXPOSE 3838

CMD R --no-save -e 'shiny::runApp("app.R", port = 3838, host = "0.0.0.0")'
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    image: test:latest
    ports:
      - '80:3838'
    user: 'root'
```

I built the image:

```
doug:~/Projects/test$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  34.82kB
Step 1/6 : FROM rocker/shiny-verse
 ---> 6ca67ad3f372
Step 2/6 : COPY test_app mountpoints/apps/test_app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d34eee9154b
Step 3/6 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get upgrade -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6a9f0856291a
Step 4/6 : WORKDIR mountpoints/apps/test_app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 30897306d02b
Step 5/6 : EXPOSE 3838
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0affe5f79ba4
Step 6/6 : CMD R --no-save -e 'shiny::runApp("app.R", port = 3838, host = "0.0.0.0")'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1ce09f39c2ce
Successfully built 1ce09f39c2ce
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

I then tried to run with docker-compose:

```
doug:~/Projects/test$ docker-compose run test

R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> shiny::runApp("app.R", port = 3838, host = "0.0.0.0")
Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3838
```

Now, when I try to visit the app at http://0.0.0.0:3838 in my browser I get:

> This site can’t be reached
> 0.0.0.0 refused to connect.

I tried some variations:
127.0.0.1:3838
localhost:3838
127.0.0.1:3838/test_app
localhost:3838/test_app

In all cases, I saw the same message and was unable to view my app in the browser.

I tried experimenting with the ports part of the docker-compose file above:

ports:

- '80:3838'

Tried:

```
'3838:3838', '127.0.0.1:3838', '3838'
```

In each case I rebuilt the image and tried again, but I was still unable to view my app in the browser.

How can I run my Shiny app and view it in the browser?

Comment: The `ports` first number is the ***host*** port, the second number is the ***container*** port. When you are connecting from outside of the container (i.e., from your browser), you should connect to the *host* port number, which is 80 (if your OS's security posture allows docker containers to run services on ports under 1024). So either change your `docker-compose.yml` to read `- '3838:3838'` or browse to `127.0.0.1:80` (or just `http://127.0.0.1`, since `:80` is inferred from `http://`). See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried just going to 127.0.0.1 but I have Nextcloud app running there already. So I then tried changing `ports` per your suggestion to `- '3838:3838'`. I then ran with docker-compose and tried both http://127.0.0.1:3838/ and http://127.0.0.1:3838/ test_app but saw the same error message

Comment: This is `docker-compose` doing it to you. I ran something similar and could not find it with `docker-compose run test`, but when I did simply `docker run -p 3838:3838 --rm test`, I connected to `http://localhost:3838` immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I know you are intending to use `docker-compose`, my first step to make sure basic networking was working. I was able to connect with:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 3838:3838 test
```

Then I tried basic `docker`, and I was able to get this to work

```
docker-compose run -p 3838:3838 test
```

(Again, the need for `-p 3838:3838` ...)

From there, it appears that `docker-compose` is really meant to start things with `up` instead. I was also able to see the shiny app when I *instead* (after stopping the above container) running

```
docker-compose up -d test
```

So the difference is between `run` and `up`. Reading https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/, I found this:

> Commands you use with `run` start in new containers with configuration defined by that of the service, including volumes, links, and other details. However, there are two important differences.
>
> First, the command passed by `run` overrides the command defined in the service configuration. For example, if the `web` service configuration is started with `bash`, then `docker-compose run web python app.py` overrides it with `python app.py`.
>
> The second difference is that the `docker-compose run` command ***does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration***. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports. If you do want the service’s ports to be created and mapped to the host, specify the `--service-ports` flag ...

(emphasis mine)

Which led me to try (and succeed with):

```
docker-compose run --service-ports test
```

And with all of those, `http://localhost:3838` worked (for me on windows ... should work for others as well, though if not `localhost` then try `127.0.0.1`).

---

My files, slightly-modified for speed of testing, and because I don't have your `test_app`:

### Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse
EXPOSE 3838
CMD R --no-save -e 'library(shiny); runExample("01_hello", port=3838, host="0.0.0.0");'
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    image: test:latest
    ports:
      - "3838:3838"
    user: 'root'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I cannot test it right now due to a seperate issue where I cannot stop any containers and thus get message 'port is already allocated'. Once I figure that out I'm looking forwards to testing this solution. Thanks again!

Comment: (I ran into a similar situation where I had done `up -d` and forgotten it was running. Are you saying you're unable to `docker-compose down test` or `docker-compose stop test`? Odd ... okay, no rush, I'm here all week ;-)

Comment: (Have you tried plain-old `docker stop image_name` and `docker rm image_name`? Realize the name will likely be something crazy, not `test`. `docker ps` helps here, in case you aren't already familiar.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. In case it's of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057692/cannot-stop-containers-without-restart?noredirect=1#comment113275851_64057692

Comment: I'm struggling with Docker, in general today.

Comment: It works! I restarted my laptop, rebuilt the image and ran with `docker-compose run --service-ports test`. Can't tell you how good it feels to see this working. Sincere thank you