# Cannot stop containers without restart

Tags: docker

I have several running containers:

```
doug:~$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
272cd5d5ea09        test:latest         "/bin/sh -c 'R --no-…"   2 hours ago         Up 6 minutes                    3838/tcp            test_test_run_9
1cf76a8c0c3d        test:latest         "/bin/sh -c 'R --no-…"   2 hours ago         Up 6 minutes                    3838/tcp            test_test_run_8
692cc601d53f        test:latest         "/bin/sh -c 'R --no-…"   3 hours ago         Up 6 minutes                    3838/tcp            test_test_run_7
b291c7da6874        test:latest         "/bin/sh -c 'R --no-…"   3 hours ago         Up 6 minutes                    3838/tcp            test_test_run_6
eaa7bc06b2df        test:latest         "/bin/sh -c 'R --no-…"   3 hours ago         Up 6 minutes                    3838/tcp            test_test_run_5
ad97b2e8d608        test:latest         "/bin/sh -c 'R --no-…"   3 hours ago         Up 6 minutes                    3838/tcp            test_test_run_4
d86971921209        8f34deadf354        "/bin/sh -c 'R --no-…"   3 hours ago         Up Less than a second           3838/tcp            test_test_run_3
2b433711545d        608f619f1146        "/bin/sh -c 'R --no-…"   3 hours ago         Up Less than a second           3838/tcp            test_test_run_2
14f3dbb2e854        ed16f53ad294        "/bin/sh -c 'R --no-…"   3 hours ago         Restarting (1) 51 seconds ago
```

I am unable to stop any of them:

```
doug:~$ sudo !!
sudo docker stop 272
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 272: Cannot kill container 272cd5d5ea092880a81a67744a224f32f1ed2a8f1cad0f1e5b666b9095eaaf3a: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
```

I found this bug report on Github:

- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/254

The suggestion in that post is to use:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

This does not work for me. When I run that command and type docker container ls, I still see all the same running containers above.

All I can do is restart my computer. After restart, the containers no longer run. However, if I then try to run a new container, I get an error:

```
doug:~/Projects/test$ docker-compose run test
Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
ERROR: unable to insert jump to DOCKER-ISOLATION rule in FORWARD chain:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -I FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION: iptables v1.6.0: Couldn't load target `DOCKER-ISOLATION':No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
 (exit status 2))
```

In order to get this new container to run, I tried restarting docker:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

This does allow me to run my new container afterwards with `docker-compose run test`, however, now all of the containers from above are running, not just the new one.

Summary:

- I am unable to stop any containers unless I restart my laptop
- After restart, the containers are no longer running. However, if I want to run a new container it doesn't work without `sudo systemctl restart docker.service` and then when I do that all of the old containers start running again.

How can I stop, delete, whatever all these old containers?

```
doug:~$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:02:36 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:01:06 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

I'm using a laptop running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: force remove the containers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried: `sudo docker rm -f 6ba
Error response from daemon: Could not kill running container 6ba955908b0d15533ebcd178e4878b7655b6a4fd8ee9718cb1a1ff0801365347, cannot remove - Cannot kill container 6ba955908b0d15533ebcd178e4878b7655b6a4fd8ee9718cb1a1ff0801365347: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
`

Comment: It would be interesting to try and find out why this is happenign. But for removal, you can alsso find the paths on your machine where these containers exist on your host and remove them also. Not sure what effect it would have though. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/where-are-docker-images-stored-docker-container-paths-explained/

Comment: alternatively, I keep seeing the permission denied error. are you running the commands as the right user?

Comment: Re the right user. I am not sure actually. I have two users on  my laptop, personal and 'work' and they both use docker. Both are sudo users. Either way, I have tried stopping the containers under each login yet get the same issue

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/can-not-stop-docker-container-permission-denied-error/41142/5

Comment: Do tell if any of the mentioned works..

Comment: Hi, I tried the advice on that forum, `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove apparmor
sudo service docker restart
docker system prune --all --volumes` but my issue persists :/

Comment: `doug:~/Projects/test$ docker-compose stop
bash: /snap/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory
doug:~/Projects/test$ docker-compose down
bash: /snap/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory
doug:~/Projects/test$ 

`

Comment: how abt this -> `sudo aa-remove-unknown`. Related to it https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20554

Comment: I restarted my laptop again and reinstalled docker-compose from apt. This appears to have solved my issue